# How can I compare two nested lists and counting number of occurences and keep into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have two nested lists,

```
l1 = [[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[2,2]]
l2 = [[1],[3],[3,4],[1],[1,2],[3],[4],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[2,2]]
```

I want to figure out how many times each element of `l1` find out in `l2` and keep the value into a dictionary where the key of a dictionary is the number of occurrences of each element and value will be the element itself. what I did as follows:

```
dic = {}
for item in l1:
  count = 0
  for items in l2:
     if item == items:
        count += 1
  dic[count] = item
return dic
```

The answer would be `dic = {3:[1], 1:[2], 2:[1,2], 3:[3], 1:[2,2]}`
But I got `dic = {1:[2], 2:[1,2], 3:[3]}`. I didn't get the exact answer. Could you please help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: `{3:[1], 1:[2], 2:[1,2], 3:[3], 1:[2,2]}` is not possible (duplicated keys)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple items in `l1` having identical counts.

Both `[2,2]` and `[2]` each occur once, so when they are assigned into the dictionary on overwrites the other.

Reverse this line:

```
dic[count] = item
```

to this:

```
dic[item] = count
```

keep in mind that you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary so your requested output is impossible!

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[2,2]]
l2 = [[1],[3],[3,4],[1],[1,2],[3],[4],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[2,2]]
dic = {}
for i in l1:
  item = tuple(i)
  count = 0
  for j in l2:
     items = tuple(j)
     if item == items:
        count += 1
  dic[item] = count

print  dic
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2): 2, (2,): 1, (3,): 3, (1,): 3, (2, 2): 1}
```

dict key is list and value is count